# JavaScript - browserHandler is undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I´m not a JavaScript Dev. 
My SharePoint 2010 Site with custom code (Running on SharePoint 2013) does not work correctly.
The click event on a link is not working. 
When I´m using a debuger (IE F12) I get the message that "browserHandler is undefined".

Is the following code correct?

```
var browserHandler;
if (element.addEventListener) {
    browserHandler = function (e) {
        return handler.call(element, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(e));
    };
    element.addEventListener(eventName, browserHandler, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
    browserHandler = function () {
        var e = {}; //Message: browserHandler is undefined
        try  {
            e = Sys.UI.DomElement._getWindow(element).event;
        } catch (ex) {
        }
        return handler.call(element, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(e));
    };
    element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, browserHandler);
}
```

Comment: Is that a verbatim copy-paste of the code? If not, I suspect there's a typo in the real code.

Comment: Is the error really happening on the line with `var e = {};`? I don't see any way that the error could be there.

Comment: Are you getting any syntax errors in the console? That will prevent the function from being defined.

Comment: Maby "handler" is undefined?